# Uploading a BLOB file with YML content

Tags: javascript, web, yaml, blob

I am trying for about 3 months to UPLOAD e BLOB file from my HTML/JS page to a Backend, with no success.

The content of the blob is text taken from a YML configuration file (bootstrap.yml of springboot). The point is that when I try to upload it, it is like the IDENTATION goes away and the Backend interprets the YML as a normal .properties file (key: value).

From POSTMAN, when I try to upload a file with the same content, everything works fine...

Any ideas ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Please provide some code, otherwise we cannot debug. What does your server endpoint expect? `application/octet-stream` or `multipart/form-data`? What does your request in Postman look like?

Comment: @Mushroomator, it expects multipart/form-data. I can see the same headers from POSTMAN and form browser inspector also...